# Scheduling task using java spring mvc

Tags: java, calendar, quartz-scheduler

I need to schedule a task to run automatically in java..I need the same functionality of window scheduling.I have done for daily,yearly but stuck when i came to weekly  scheduling..not getting how to do this. I am using java calendar.Please help to find one good solutions.

Any help or ideas would be appreciable

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-quartz is worth a read.

Comment: Checkout [Task Execution and Scheduling](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) chapter

Answer (score 8):

Scheduling a task in Spring can be done in 4 ways, as shown below.

**1. Task scheduling using fixed delay attribute in `@Scheduled` annotation.**

```
public class DemoServiceBasicUsageFixedDelay {
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    // @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void demoServiceMethod() {
        System.out.println("Method executed at every 5 seconds. Current time is :: " + new Date());
    }
}
```

**2. Task scheduling using cron expression in `@Scheduled` annotation**

```
@Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * ?")
public void demoServiceMethod() {
    System.out.println("Method executed at every 5 seconds. Current time is :: " + new Date());
}
```

**3. Task scheduling using cron expression from properties file.**

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${cron.expression}")
public void demoServiceMethod() {
    System.out.println("Method executed at every 5 seconds. Current time is :: " + new Date());
}
```

**4. Task scheduling using cron expression configured in context configuration**

```
public class DemoServiceXmlConfig {
    public void demoServiceMethod() {
        System.out.println("Method executed at every 5 seconds. Current time is :: " + new Date());
    }
}
```

**XML config for #4**

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>
        <task:scheduled ref="demoServiceXmlConfig" method="demoServiceMethod" cron="#{applicationProps['cron.expression']}"></task:scheduled>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

More explanation on http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/23/4-ways-to-schedule-tasks-in-spring-3-scheduled-example/

Hope this helps you.